# Get ID from table of a fortify command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Using user entered variables, I'm trying to make a .bat that executes a fortify scan automatic (and upload it, but less important here). However, I'm stuck at a for loop command after I ask the user for the following:

- username (%user%)
- password (%pwd%)
- project (%project%)
- version (%version%)

The part where I'm stack at, is retrieving the ID from the below table which comes from a fortifyclient command, where user and password are variables I ask to the user:

```
fortifyclient listProjectVersions -user %user% -password %pwd% -url https://fortify:0000/ssc

ID      Name                    Version
29153   Sales Dep.              Gdpr
xxx     Xxx                     Xxx
```

I'm able to set the variables, get the project name and do something with them by using the below command which retrieves the above table, however, I'm not there yet.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,4 delims=" %F in ('fortifyclient listProjectVersions -user %user% -password %pwd% -url https://fortify:0000/ssc ^| find "%project%"') do @(for %A in (%F) do @echo %A)
```

The above command provides me the following result, if project is set to "Gdpr" and the client provides his credentials:

```
29153
Sales
Dep.
Gdpr
```

I don't need the above, I wish to get only the ID, 29153. **How do I get that?**

Is there a better way than the way I did it?

P.S.: I'm not responsible for giving those table columns and setting up the fortify projects.

P.P.S: The for loop above is using the syntax for direct cmd input because I wanted to test it first.

Edit: Apologies for the bad explanation earlier.

Comment: Your code should not output anything because your input example never shows `Gdpr` in the output.

Comment: how does `find "Gdpr"` correspond to the output of `fortifyclient`?

Comment: @Stephan, right sorry, I copied it from a test that I performed directly in the cmd prompt. "Gdpr" will be changed to a variable such as "%project%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few assumptions with this code and I am not the greatest mind reader. You said you only want the ID so you should only be trying to get token 1.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %F in ('fortifyclient listProjectVersions -user xxx -password xxx -url https://fortify:0000/ssc ^| find "Gdpr"') do echo %F
```

Comment: Apologies for the unclear OP. I've tried to make it clearer.

Comment: In the mean time I tried your solution and it does the trick. So simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET "flag=Y"&for /f "tokens=1,2,4 delims=" %F in ('fortifyclient listProjectVersions -user xxx -password xxx -url https://fortify:0000/ssc ^| find "Gdpr"') do @(for %A in (%F) do IF DEFINED flag @echo %A&SET "flag=")
```

Of course, this assumes that you are executing this command directly from the prompt, which is illogical. If you paste the code into a batch file, you could execute it repeatedly by simply entering `batchfilename` - but you'd need to change all mentions of the `metavariables` `%F` and `%A` to `%%F` and `%%A`

---

After clarification and revelation of the `gdpr` situation:

The above should still have worked (from the prompt - replace `%F` with `%%F` and `%A` with `%%A` for a batchfile line.)

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%F in ('fortifyclient listProjectVersions -user xxx -password xxx -url https://fortify:0000/ssc ^| find "Gdpr"') do echo %%F
```

should work as a batchfile line. Naturally, `set "ID=%%F"` in place of the `echo %%F` if you want to set a variable.

Comment: Alternatively `for /f "tokens=1*" %A in ("%~F") do @echo %A`

Comment: @JosefZ: Yeah, but attempting to respond with minimal changes.

Comment: _Yeah, but attempting to respond with minimal changes_: Then, consider that my suggestion is about 23 chars shorter:)))